# is jargon related to a frameWork (concept)

Tags: programming-languages

If this is not the right place to ask this question please inform where it would belong, to change it...

I have a doubt for the correct word or concept in english language [not my native], about the relationship of

> language to framework

for example i work with

> objective C, with the cocoa touch frame work || python with the django frame work

My comparison is between natural languages and formal languages,

So would be in a natural language

> english  and the frame work a [computer, it]jargon?

Does this make sense?

Or what other concept would be the relationship between natural language - framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frameworks are like sets of idioms leading up to a full culture in your terms. For instance you might have American English or Australian English with distinct customs, habits, slangs and so forth. Jargons would be a part of that but not a full equivalent. Java for instance has been referred to as the [Kingdom of Nouns](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html) with a very different culture than something like Lisp.

Some languages have cultures that are very open and free-wheeling, others are more constrained or "buttoned down". Indentation is very important in Python Culture but much less so in most other language cultures. Some are very open while others are more insular and isolationist. Some are older than others but still less complex or developed. Some tend toward simplicity over time with better tools and more efficient coding whilst others stay just as obtuse as the day they were first released. Trade languages like English or Indonesian tend to be much less complex than languages that are more isolated like Navajo or Finnish.

Which leads me to my point. Many people talk about the ideal programming language without any heed for its culture. Pick a language for its culture, not for the language itself.